# Neo4j Passing distinct nodes through WITH in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query, where there are 3 MATCHES, connected with WITH, searching through 3 paths.

```
MATCH (:File {name: 'A'})-[:FILE_OF]->(:Fun {name: 'B'})-->(ent:CFGEntry)-[:Flows*]->()-->(expr:CallExpr {name: 'C'})-->()-[:IS_PARENT]->(Callee {name: 'd'}) 
WITH expr, ent 

MATCH (expr)-->(:Arg {chNum: '1'})-->(id:Id) 
WITH id, ent

MATCH (entry)-[:Flows*]->(:IdDecl)-[:Def]->(sym:Sym) 
WHERE id.name = sym.name 
RETURN id.name
```

The query returns two distinct id and one distinct entry, and 7 distinct sym.

The problem is that since in the second MATCH I pass "WITH id, entry", and two distinct id were found, two instances of entry is passed to the third match instead of 1, and the run time of the third match unnecessarily gets doubled at least.

I am wondering if anyone know how I should write this query to just make use of one single instance of entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet will be to aggregate id, but then you'll need to adjust your logic in the third part of your query accordingly:

```
MATCH (:File {name: 'A'})-[:FILE_OF]->(:Fun {name: 'B'})-->(ent:CFGEntry)-[:Flows*]->()-->(expr:CallExpr {name: 'C'})-->()-[:IS_PARENT]->(Callee {name: 'd'}) 
WITH expr, ent 

MATCH (expr)-->(:Arg {chNum: '1'})-->(id:Id) 
WITH collect(id.name) as names, ent

MATCH (entry)-[:Flows*]->(:IdDecl)-[:Def]->(sym:Sym) 
WHERE sym.name in names 
RETURN sym.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my problem. But a more general question: You leverage the fact that I do not use id as a node later for a search based on MATCH. In case, I have MATCH (id) in a later match, how do you avoid this issue (duplicating ent)? We can not use your solution because  we can not pass the result of collect(a) AS b to MATCH (b), because it expects a node and we pass it a list of nodes.

Comment: You have a few options open to you. You can always collect `id` separately on the same line you collect `id.name`. That will give you, for each expr, the collection of ids and the collection of id names. And where you have to do `MATCH (b)`, you can UNWIND the collection back to rows of nodes before you do your match.